# LinkedIn - Unable to embed some videos - javascript error on firefox

Tags: video, html5-video, linkedin-api, embed

In our platform, we are embedding some videos. 
On Firefox, it's seem there are an issue embedding your players.

If you do a simple codepen with the following contents :

```
<iframe
src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:7089952243906400256?compact=true" 
width"800" height="650">
</iframe>
```

It's working on Chrome, but not on Firefox

**Problem:**
There is a Javascript error preventing it to play
I'm trying to play an embed URL on an iframe (video) without error.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow removed my html. It's 
iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:7089952243906400256?compact=true"